# Is synchronized locking a Reentrantlock, or only its object?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

The normal pattern with ReentrantLock and lock()/unlock() is like this:

```
lck.lock();
try {
    // ...
}
finally {
    lck.unlock();
}
```

Can this be refactored to

```
synchronized(lck) {
    // ...
}
```

?
And why?

Comment: No it can't. They are different mechanisms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between synchronized and re-entrant lock?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072422/difference-between-synchronized-and-re-entrant-lock)

Comment: No. The main idea behind locks is to avoid the coarse grained synchronized blocks - IOW, it is an improvement over synchronized blocks. If you use `synchronized(lck)` you're basically treating lck like any other object, and not really using the lock concept.

Comment: I would recommend reading the [Oracle Tutorial on Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html). With `synchronized`, you use the object's intrinsic lock. The intrinsic locks allow reentrant. Explicit locking via locks is a different mechanism.

Answer (score 8):

These are different things. `synchronized` is built into the language and can be used with any object. What it does is lock its **intrinsic lock**. Every single object has one. As it's a built-in mechanism, you don't need a `try-finally` block—the lock is always unlocked when the control exits the `synchronized` block. So as long as your code actually exits that block, the lock will be unlocked.

`ReentrantLock` is a special class. It locks some special internal object, that is probably implementation-specific. It does *not* lock its intrinsic lock. You could, of course, lock that one too—but it doesn't normally make any sense. This code will almost certainly deadlock, for example:

```
final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
new Thread(() -> {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        System.out.println("Thread 1 locked the lock");
        try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch (Exception ex) {}
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.println("Thread 1 locked lock's intrinsic lock");
        }
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}).start();
new Thread(() -> {
    synchronized (lock) {
        System.out.println("Thread 2 locked lock's intrinsic lock");
        try { Thread.sleep(200); } catch (Exception ex) {}
        lock.lock();
        try {
            System.out.println("Thread 2 locked the lock");
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

It deadlocks because two threads lock two different things in different order.

It certainly feels like `ReentrantLock` does almost the same thing as `synchronized`. It works similarly, but `synchronized` is both more convenient and less powerful. So unless you need any features of `ReentrantLock`, like interruptible lock attempts or lock time-outs, you should stick with `synchronized` for the purpose of reentrant locking, and use any objects for that. Simple `private final Object lock = new Object()` will do just fine. Note that `final` will prevent confusing things that could happen if you change that object at some moment; some IDEs will issue a warning if you omit `final`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are aware of differences in explicit and implicit locking provided by `Lock` and `synchronized` respectively.

I believe you are looking for a reason saying what's wrong in using instances of class implementing `Lock` interfaces inside `synchronized` block as in `synchronized(lock)`.

Could it be refactored? **Yes**.

But should you be doing that? **Not with instances of classes implementing Lock interface**

**Why?** - Well.

It is all right if you just use `lock` *only* inside `synchronized` **however** you leave the possibility to other developers to misuse the code say for e.g. what if someone tomorrow tries calling `Lock` methods inside `synchronized(lock)` something like below.

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
synchronized(lock){ //You write this
    // lock.lock();  // I am not taking a lock here
    System.out.println("See emily play");
    ...
    ...
    ... // after 100 lines of code 
    //callAnotherMethod(lock); //Someone else does this
    lock.unlock();   //Someone else does this
}
```

The above code is horrible but to give you an example, in the above example if you do not call `lock()`, then you end up with `IllegalMonitorStateException`. If you do call (uncomment above) `lock.lock()` it makes no difference.

Not to mention the `callAnotherMethod(lock)` where you are passing the lock instance and what sort of unexpected behaviours it can introduce.

Keep in mind that is one such example.

Bottom line, if it works correctly by any chance, it is just wasting resources and time and would serve no advantage/purpose. More importantly there is no guarantee that it **would not introduce regressions** in the future. And if there would be any such regressions, you may end up wasting significant amount of time because of misuse of concepts.

Softwares are always designed with Open-Close principle. You would be writing the code that would violate it very clearly.

In case if you do want to use fine grained locks using `synchronized` then you can make use of the below

```
Object obj1 = new Object();
Object obj2 = new Object();

public void doSomething(){
    synchronised(obj1){
    ...
    }
}

public void doSomethingMore(){
    synchronised(obj2){
    ...
    }
}
```

But then again, I don't see any reason why you would not use multiple lock instances to achieve the above.